# Regular Expression matching extra unwanted content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a parameter stored in a html comment using regex. However when I execute the expression it return the widest string possible and not all the possible matches.

So I have some content that might include this string:

`<!--url:/new--><!--title:My Title-->`

I use the following simply expression to get the url I need:

`/<!--url:(.*)-->/`

The issue I have is that the result match part of the title which is of course valid but not what I was looking for

`["<!--url:/new--><!--title:My Title-->", "/new--><!--title:My Title"]`

There is workarounds I can use like making sure there is a line break after each parameter line but I prefer to  have a solid regex and also of course understand what I missing out.

PS: Please comment if you come up with a better title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the regex non-greedy:

```
/<!--url:(.*?)-->/
```

You can test this regex by clicking here:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/hS6zP5/3)